# Allow A-star algorithm to bypass x number of obstacles

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, path-finding, a-star, maze

Right now I have this maze:

[image: maze]

The nodes marked with *S* and *E* represent the start and end of this maze.

The nodes colored with orange are representing obstacles which at the moment cannot be bypassed.

My goal is to allow the A* algorithm to bypass x number of obstacles and get to the end in the fastest possible way.

My A* algorithm currently navigates through it like this:

[image: like this].

But i want it to navigate like this if I allow 1 obstacle to be bypassed:

[image: this]

and like this if i allow 2 obstacles to be bypassed:

[image: this]

How can I modify the A* algorithm to achieve this? Is there maybe an alternative algorithm that could help me with this problem?

Comment: For your last example there will be two equal length shortest paths

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the nodes in your graph and generate instances for each number of bypasses. I.e., you will create several layers of the graph and start on layer 0 (you have bypassed 0 obstacles already). Whenever you go to an obstacle node, you switch to the next layer (i.e., there are edges to neighboring obstacle nodes of the next layer and edges to neighboring non-obstacle nodes of the same layer). Create as many layers as you want obstacles to be bypassed. If you arrive at any instance of the target cell (on any layer), you are done.